# Conexion a Sql Server mediante JAVA - Autenticacion de Windows

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Quiero conectarme a Sql Server mediante Java con Autenticacion de Windows pero me sale el siguiente error: Este controlador no está configurado para la autenticación integrada. ClientConnectionId:0b65956b-a286-4aef-a372-ab741a239761

Este el código que utilizo:

```
public Connection getConectar(){
        Connection cn=null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=VENTAS2017;integratedSecurity=true");
            System.out.println("Conexion Exitosa");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ERROR"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return cn;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La documentación oficial dice:

> El controlador JDBC admite el uso de la autenticación integrada de
>   tipo 2 en sistemas operativos Windows a través de la propiedad de
>   cadena de conexión `integratedSecurity`. Para utilizar la
>   autenticación integrada, copie el archivo **`sqljdbc_auth.dll`** en un
>   directorio en la ruta del sistema de Windows, justo donde está
>   instalado el controlador JDBC.
>
> Los archivos **`sqljdbc_auth.dll`** se instalan en la ubicación
>   siguiente:
>
> ```
> <Directorio de instalación>\sqljdbc_<versión>\<idioma>\auth\
> ```

En [esta ruta](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774) puedes descargar el controlador donde viene la DLL.

La documentación oficial completa se encuentra en [esta liga](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.90).aspx#Connectingintegrated).