# No puedo conectarme a SQL Server desde Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, eclipse

¿qué tal?

Estoy tratando de conectarme a una BD que hice en SQL Server 2017 con JDBC de Java en Eclipse con el siguiente String de conexión:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTOP-4VA2FRR1;databaseName=GestionEmpresa", "LAPTOP-4VA2FRR1\fdc", "");
```

La conexión la estoy llevando a cabo usando autenticación de windows. Probé con esta conexión pero tampoco funcionó

```
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=GestionEmpresa;integratedSecurity=true");
```

Llevo todo el día buscando cual puede ser el error pero no encuentro ninguna solución. 
Debe ser un problema del string porque tengo otras BD con esa conexión y puedo acceder sin problemas desde otras aplicaciones desarrolladas en C#.

Comment: La respuesta a esta pregunta la puedes encontrar en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48648/conexion-a-sql-server-mediante-java-autenticacion-de-windows) de este mismo sitio

Comment: Hola, no se trata del mismo error

Comment: No se pudo realizar la conexión con el host localhost, instancia con nombre sqlexpress. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verifique los nombres del servidor y de instancia, compruebe que no hay ningún firewall bloqueando el tráfico UDP al puerto 1434. Para SQL Server 2005 o posterior, verifique que el servicio SQL Server Browser se está ejecutando en el host.
esa es la excepción que me arroja

Comment: Entonces tenías que haber puesto el error que estabas teniendo, porque sino no tenemos manera de saber que ocurre. No obstante, perfectamente puedes estar teniendo el mismo problema, el error indica que se agotó el tiempo de espera para intentar realizar la conexión, el resto son causas comunes de este error. ¿Tu utilizas el DLL necesario para poder usar la autenticación de Windows desde JDBC?