# SQL server conexion con java Este controlador no está configurado para la autenticación integrada

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

actualmente presento un problema con mi conexión de sql server a Java, exactamente no se de donde proviene el problema pero ya este me esta superando, entiendo que vendria desde mi controlador y la autenticación pero ya la instale y todo y me sigue dando el mismo problema, el colmo es que ya hace un tiempo hice un programa con el uso de sql server y este no presentaba ningun fallo e incluso me pedía menos cosas al momento de hacer la conexión.

```js
package prueba_red_local;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexion {
    
    public static Connection getConexion(){
        
        String conexionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
                + "database=ListaIp;integratedSecurity=true;"
                + "encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"
                + "user=prueba;"
                + "password=prueba;";
        
        try{
            Connection xion = DriverManager.getConnection(conexionUrl);
            return xion;
        } catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            return null;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Este es el codigo de mi conexion, mi sistema operativo es 64bits windows, tengo el controlador Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server, SQL Management Studio 18.11, Java jre1.8.0_211 y todo lo programo desde netbeans 8.2, tambien agregue el `mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8` a la librería, si alguien me puede ayudar estaria muy agradecido

Este es el mensaje completo del error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Este controlador no está configurado para la autenticación integrada. ClientConnectionId:2bcfc9bc-f072-4c8d-bc2d-eed6299965ef
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Conexion a Sql Server mediante JAVA - Autenticacion de Windows](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48648/conexion-a-sql-server-mediante-java-autenticacion-de-windows)

Comment: Esa pregunta ya la vi, y la intente de muchas maneras y ninguna me solucionaba el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo que te pasaba es lo siguiente:
en la url de conexión indicabas que 'integratedSecurity=true', eso indica que la conexión se realiza con seguridad integrada de windows, es decir, con tu usuario de windows, pero realmente el usuario de bbdd es 'prueba'.
Esto hace que el driver de conexión a BBDD intente logearse con tu usuario de Windows y no con el usuario de BBDD ('prueba') para lo cual el driver no está preparado (tal como indica el mensaje de error).
Al eliminar de la cadena de conexión ese parámetro ('integratedSecurity=true') el driver intenta conectarse de forma 'normal' con user/pwd y la conexión se establece correctmente.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Termine solucionando el problema de la siguiente manera:
Termine cambiando la la clase conexion y dejándola de esta manera

```js
package prueba_red_local;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexion {
    
    public static Connection getConexion(){
        
        String conexionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
                + "database=ListaIp;"
                + "user=prueba;"
                + "password=prueba;";
        
        try{
            Connection xion = DriverManager.getConnection(conexionUrl);
            return xion;
        } catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            return null;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

No me explico porque ahora me funciona pero bueno, ya funciona.
Esto lo hago porque puedo prescindir de los certificado y la seguridad.

Answer (score 0):

tuve el mismo problema y logre solucionar mi error al conectarme con el sqlserver. Por si tienen el mismo error lo que hize fue cambiar de driver al 11.2.0.jre18 y aumentarle al string de conexión esto al final: String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTOP-C90H2UFB\SQLEXPRESS:1433;database=bdventas;"+
"encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";

Comment: No va a funcionar si se agrega ""jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTOP-C90H2UFB\SQLEXPRES"